# Escaping special characters in ruby

Tags: ruby, postgresql, character-encoding

This is a common question, but just can't seem to find the answer without resorting to unreliable regular expressions.

Basically if there is a `\302\240` or similar combination in a string I want to replace it with the real character.

I am using PLruby for this, hence the warn.

```
obj = {"a"=>"some string with special chars"}
warn obj.inspect
NOTICE: {"Outputs"=>["a\302\240b"]} <- chars are escaped
warn "\302\240"
NOTICE:   <-- there is a non breaking space here, like I want
warn "#{json.inspect}"
NOTICE: {"Outputs"=>["a\302\240"b]} <- chars are escaped
```

So these can be decoded when I use a string literal, but with the "#{x}" format the \xxx placeholders are never decoded into characters.

How would I assign the same string as the middle command yields?

Ruby Version: 1.8.5

Comment: No idea what you mean, sorry... Maybe you should rephrase the question. Especially the code and output seems very strange to me..

Comment: I just want to use .inspect without the ridiculous escaping it does.

Comment: The purpose of inspect on the built-in types is to give you a representation of an object that can be used as a literal. That's not "ridiculous". You seem to be looking for something entirely different, maybe the solution would be a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned that you're using PL/ruby. That suggests that your strings are actually `bytea` values (the PostgreSQL version of a BLOB) using the [old "escape" format](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-binary.html#AEN5217). The escape format encodes non-ASCII values in octal with a leading `\` so a bit of [`gsub`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) and [`Array#pack`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-pack) should sort you out:

```
bytes = s.gsub(/\\([0-8]{3})/) { [ $1.to_i(8) ].pack('C') }
```

That will expand the escape values in `s` to raw bytes and leave them in `bytes`. You're still dealing with binary data though so just trying to display it on a console won't necessarily do anything useful. If you know that you're dealing with comprehensible strings then you'll have to figure out what encoding they're in and use [String](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html) methods to sort out the encoding.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. As the escape format was fine for postgres, but PLruby escapes the backslashes causing a bunch of \xxx stuff to be stored in the tables. Thanks.

Comment: @Keyo: There are PostgreSQL functions for working with `bytea` formats: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-binarystring.html#FUNCTIONS-BINARYSTRING-OTHER

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you just want to use `.to_s` instead?

Comment: I specifically need the {"a"=>"b"} json like output that inspect returns. to_s uses something entirely different. I'm just looking for a way to replace occurrences of \xxx with the actual character (unescape it).

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to just convert it to json, instead of trying to inspect some values and then gsubbing out the inspected version? Try `require 'json'; json = {"Outputs"=>["a\302\240b"]}.to_json; puts json`